Trying to translate property of covariant derivative to abstract index notation
Let $X$ be a smooth vector field on $M$, $A$ is some smooth tensor field and $f$ is a smooth function. One property of the covariant derivative is: $$\nabla_X(fA)=(\nabla_Xf)A+f\nabla_XA\tag{0}$$
Explicitly writing down the arguments and shifting to total covariant derivative,
$$\nabla_X(fA)(\ldots)=(\nabla_Xf)A(\ldots)+f\nabla_XA(\ldots)$$
$$\implies(\nabla(fA))(\ldots,X)=X(f)A(\ldots)+f(\nabla A)(\ldots,X)\tag{1}$$
Now in another book (Differential Geometry by Liang), introduction to covariant derivative is in abstract notation, let $A$ be a $(3,2)$ tensor field. Then its covariant derivative is defined as $\nabla_a$ - I'm thinking the "covariant derivative" in this context is the total covariant derivative, since it adds a covariant index after acting on $A$. A property of this derivative is given as
$$\nabla_a(\alpha A_{\ \ \ \ \ ef}^{bcd})=\alpha\nabla_aA^{bcd}_{\ \ \ \ \ ef}$$ if $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. This agrees with eq. (1) if we substitute $f$ by some real number. But I'm stuck on how to get the abstract index notation version of eq. (1) if $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$.
Any idea on how to express eq. (0) in abstract index notation? My guess (assuming $A$ is a (3,2) tensor) is that it'll be something like:
$$\nabla_a(fA_{\ \ \ \ \ ef}^{bcd})X^a=(\nabla_af)X^aA_{\ \ \ \ \ ef}^{bcd}+f\nabla_aA_{\ \ \ \ \ ef}^{bcd}X^a$$
But I'm not sure about this - again because of the first term on the RHS. Any confirmation or correction would be appreciated..

Back to studying abstract index notation. In fact, Liang & Zhou nicely write a bit more about that topic than one usually finds elsewhere. The question in your last sentence is puzzling because equation (0) is the standard derivative property of a connection that everybody else is using. You can find zillions of sources of which most transcribe that for you in ordinary component index notation. It is highly recommended to get familiar with this and turn to abstract index notation when necessary (happens rarely).

The question about (1) is incomprehensible and we would need to know from which book that is from.

@KurtG. I have edited the question to remove unnecessary info surrounding $\omega_X$ (I had introduced it hoping that the first term in eq. (1) RHS could be somehow forced to act on arguments $(\ldots,X)$ instead of $(\ldots)$. By $(\ldots)$, I just mean the arguments of the tensor. Why do I even include the arguments in the equation? Because the definition of total covariant derivative $\nabla$, as derived from the covariant derivative $\nabla_X$ involves writing down the arguments and shifting $X$ into the arguments of the total covariant derivative.

@KurtG. (cont'd) In the last equation, I've taken a specific example for $A$ so that writing its indices is less cumbersome. So my question is, similarly assuming $A$ in eq. (1) to be a (3,2) tensor, what's the way to write that equation in abstract notation? More specifically, I'm stuck with the first term on the RHS. I've written my guess as to what it would be at the end of the question, but I'm not sure about it. It'll be nice to get some confirmation or correction

You should really step back from abstract index notation until you have understood the widely used stuff first. I realize now that $A$ isn't just a vector field. In that case things like this must thoroughly be studied. I hope your book helps in this regard (I am not familiar with it). Another post dealing with the complicated matter of covariant derivative of $n$-forms is this.
